# Hidden Markov models with Baum-Welch algorithm using python

Tags: python, hidden-markov-model

I'm looking for some python implementation (in pure python or wrapping existing stuffs) of HMM and Baum-Welch.

Some ideas?

I've just searched in google and I've found really poor material with respect to other machine learning techniques. Why?

Answer (score 16):

The [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) has an [HMM implementation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/hmm.html). It was until recently considered as unmaintained and its usage was discouraged. However it has improved in the development version. I cannot vouch for its quality, though, as I know nothing of HMMs.

Disclaimer: I am a scikit-learn developer.

**Edit**: we have moved the HMMs outside of scikit-learn, to https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn

Comment: yeah i decide to don't use it because of unmantainement..

Comment: I think that it is improving and that we will soon be able to commit to maintaining it.

Comment: does the sklearn implementation use Baum-Welch?

Comment: Yes it does. See [`_BaseHMM`](https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn/blob/master/hmmlearn/base.py#L96) documentation for implementation details.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen NLTK?

http://www.nltk.org/

It has some classes that are suitable for this sort of thing, but somewhat application dependent.

http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#nltk.tag.hmm.HiddenMarkovModelTrainer

If you are looking for something more 'education oriented', I wrote toy trainer a while ago:

http://pastebin.com/aJG3Ukmn

Comment: thanks. i need it for gesture recognition. i'm stucked on what could be my alphabet (symbols in nltk) in my application..

Comment: @nkint Check this out: http://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub3/yang_jie_1994_1/yang_jie_1994_1.pdf

Comment: ok the data are the labels so if i use only 8 labels for clusterize the coordinates of a gesture.. alphabet is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

Comment: but still don't understand the difference between state and symbol in HiddenMarkovModelTrainer constructor

Comment: alright, how about this:  http://www.creativedistraction.com/demos/gesture-recognition-kinect-with-hidden-markov-models-hmms/  it's a step-by-step demo with code of how to build your own gesture recognizer with the kinect.  code is for Octave not python, but it seems like you are stuck on the ideas/implementation more than the particulars of the software.  of course it requires a kinect...  you might also check this out:  http://code.google.com/p/ehci/

Answer (score 3):

You can find Python implementations on:

- [Hidden Markov Models in Python - CS440: Introduction to Artifical Intelligence - CSU](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~anderson/cs440/index.html/doku.php?id=notes:hmm2)
- [Baum-Welch algorithm: Finding parameters for our HMM | Does this make sense?](http://jyyuan.wordpress.com/2014/01/28/baum-welch-algorithm-finding-parameters-for-our-hmm/)

BTW: See [Example of implementation of Baum-Welch on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958738/example-of-implementation-of-baum-welch) - the answer turns out to be in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Some implementation of basic algorithms (including Baum-welch in python) are available here: http://ai.cs.umbc.edu/icgi2012/challenge/Pautomac/baseline.php

Answer (score 1):

The [General Hidden Markov Model library](http://ghmm.org/) has python bindings and uses the Baum-Welch algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a Pyhton implementation of Baum-Welch Algorithm:

https://github.com/hamzarawal/HMM-Baum-Welch-Algorithm